# Add permission to Sharepoint file/foler function is not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm having a problem adding user permission to a specific file on Sharepoint, and I've tried with both UI and API approach.

- UI approach: It shows "Access granted", but the user is not in the access list.
- API approach: I use POST /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/invite API ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) to add permission, and double check with GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/permissions API ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)). However, the user I tried to add is not in the response permission list. Details as follows:

  - Add request (postman):

    - request:

      - request method: POST
      - request URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!B9_4qng1vEG8jqkTAC9MmAsztZ4HlLlDhKKjGSWXmyD47-FwHKeYSrnKXA21cQU-/items/01UHBHMTQDBABLHYKCP5EKEMHX6KZPMDK3/invite
      - request-id: 25a0a09c-9c1b-4b8d-9e83-905e2cb56541
      - body:

        ```
        {
             "requireSignIn": true,
             "sendInvitation": false,
             "roles": [ "write"],
             "recipients": [
                 { "email": "e2e_team_member_1@synologybat.onmicrosoft.com" }
             ]
         }
        ```
    - response:

      - status: 200 OK
      - response body:

        ```
        {
            "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
            "value": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
                    "id": "aTowIy5mfG1lbWJlcnNoaXB8ZTJlX3RlYW1fbWVtYmVyXzFAc3lub2xvZ3liYXQub25taWNyb3NvZnQuY29t",
                    "roles": [
                        "write"
                    ],
                    "grantedTo": {
                        "user": {
                            "email": "e2e_team_member_1@synologybat.onmicrosoft.com",
                            "id": "016131d5-af3d-45c7-927e-8efb816df327",
                            "displayName": "e2e_team_member_1"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        ```
  - List request (postman):

    - request:

      - request method: GET
      - request URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!B9_4qng1vEG8jqkTAC9MmAsztZ4HlLlDhKKjGSWXmyD47-FwHKeYSrnKXA21cQU-/items/01UHBHMTQDBABLHYKCP5EKEMHX6KZPMDK3/permissions
      - request-id: 16fd1b67-4bab-41af-886a-349922d86c6f
    - response: 200 OK, but the target user in Add request is not in the response body.

I'm curious that is there something I missed or if it is a temporary issue on Microsoft. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with it, thank you.